# Bucle infinito en PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

Buenas, he empezado a ver la programación orientada a objetos en php y estoy haciendo un ejercicio en el cual hago una consulta sql en la cual quiero que me muestre todas las noticias que tengo pero me genera un bucle infinito de la primera noticia que tengo guardada. Creo que es porque estoy haciendo un while con la consulta pero no se como arreglarlo.

Codigo:

```
    $objetoBBDD = new baseDatos();
    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM noticias";

    while($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($objetoBBDD->consultarBD($consulta)))
    {
        if($fila[4]==0)
            $fila[4]="No";
        else
            $fila[4]="Si";

        echo "Numero de la noticia: ".$fila[0]."<br> Titulo: ".$fila[1]."<br> Descripcion: ".$fila[2].
                "<br> Fecha: ".$fila[3]."<br> Publicada: ".$fila[4].'<br><br>';
    }
```

Comment: Hola, me explicas un poco tu condicional que tienes dentro del While

Comment: eh si.. estas haciendo while de la ejecucion de la consulta.. y eso devuelve siempre true.. la ejecucion va antes y tenes que iterar sobre el resultado...

Comment: Has intentado realizar primero la consulta y luego ya realizar el ciclo while? Utiliza la función `mysqli_num_rows()` para obtener el número de resultados de la consulta.

Comment: Ya te han indicado el error en comentarios y en respuestas. Pero nadie te ha señalado que en tu código estás mezclando POO y estilo procedural , por ejemplo al usar esta función `mysqli_fetch_array()`. No se recomienda la mezcla de estilos, si te decides por la POO, de lo cual me alegro, entonces abandona definitivamente la programación procedural en cuanto a la base de datos... No la necesitarás para nada.

Comment: Quiero utilizar solo POO, como adapto el mysqli_fetch_array?

Comment: El Manual de PHP tiene muchas lagunas, pero en eso de estilo procedural y estilo POO es muy claro, en cada función te explica claramente los dos estilos. Para este método en concreto, [puedes verlo aquí](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php). En estilo POO sería así. Almacenas el resultado: `$resultado = $objetoBBDD->consultarBD($consulta);` Y luego lo recorres: `while($row = $resultado->fetch_array()){ //...recorrer cada resultado}` En la programación POO llamas siempre los métodos que tiene el objeto, así: **`$miObjeto->unMetodo($posibleParametro);`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El bucle infinito es obvio , cada vez que regresa al `while` vuelve a llamar al método `consultarBD` por lo cuál nunca terminará. Lo ideal sería obtener el  resultado antes del `while` para luego iterar ya se con un `while` o con un `foreach` , también hubiese podido ignorar el `if else` para emplear un ternario en el `echo`.

```
$objetoBBDD = new baseDatos();
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM noticias";
$resultado = $objetoBBDD->consultarBD($consulta);//obtenemos los resultados
while($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado))
{
    echo "Numero de la noticia: ".$fila[0]."<br> Titulo: ".$fila[1].
         "<br> Descripcion: ".$fila[2].
         "<br> Fecha: ".$fila[3]."<br> Publicada: ".(($fila[4]==0)?"NO":"SI").'<br><br>';
}
```

Por los comentarios creo que intenta adaptar a `POO` `mysqli_fetch_array` esto se hace en base a los resultados.

```
$objetoBBDD = new baseDatos();
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM noticias";
$resultado = $objetoBBDD->consultarBD($consulta);//obtenemos los resultados
while($fila = $resultado->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM))
{
   echo "Numero de la noticia: ".$fila[0]."<br> Titulo: ".$fila[1].
         "<br> Descripcion: ".$fila[2].
         "<br> Fecha: ".$fila[3]."<br> Publicada: ".(($fila[4]==0)?"NO":"SI").'<br><br>';
}
```

Comment: y que añada los {} en los if else ... eso es mala practica o que los ternarios `$fila[4] = ($fila[4] == 0) ? 'NO' : 'SI'; ` hablando de OPP

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez Sí, es una opción.

Comment: El operador ternario `(($fila[4]===0)?"NO":"SI")` siempre me muestra SI independientemente si es 0 o 1. Porque?

Comment: Acabo de quitar un = de los tres que viene y me funciona

Comment: @MarioGuiber Sí, acabo de actualizar mi respuesta con `fectch_array` adaptado para `POO` , Espero le ayude . Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza un foreach en lugar de un while:

```
$resultado = mysqli_fetch_all($objetoBBDD->consultarBD($consulta), MYSQLI_NUM);
foreach ($resultado as $fila)
{
    if($fila[4]==0)
        $fila[4]="No";
    else
        $fila[4]="Si";

    echo "Numero de la noticia: ".$fila[0]."<br> Titulo: ".$fila[1]."<br> Descripcion: ".$fila[2].
            "<br> Fecha: ".$fila[3]."<br> Publicada: ".$fila[4].'<br><br>';
}
```